# Mongoose query type in typescript

Tags: typescript, mongoose

How to define `mongoose` query type `typescript`?

```
type DocType<T> = T extends Document ? T : Document;
type ID = Types.ObjectId
export const getOne = <T extends Document>(Model: Model<T>, popOptions?: string): RequestHandler =>
  catchAsync(async (req: Request<{id: ID}>, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const query = Model.findById(req.params.id) 
    if (popOptions) query = query.populate(popOptions);
    
    const doc = await query.exec() as DocType<T> | null;
   
    res.status(200).json(data);
  });
```

at here `query` after if statement show type error.  How to solve this?